# Get/Set info to html with data() jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use data() for the first time. I have a list. I want to attach info to the li elements

My html is basic. I am not using ids for anything but the div container. This is done to allow multiple ul on the page without having id conflicts.

html

```
 <div id="container">
    <ul> 
        <li><input type="checkbox"></input><label>Radio</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"></input><label>Cable</label></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

In my jquery I want to find the li elements of the container and attach a name corresponding to the text.

```
//BaseElement is my div
$(this.BaseElement).find('li').each(function () {
     var key = $(this).text();
     if (key == "Radio")
         $(this).data({ 'name' : 'Radio' });
     if (key == "Cable")
         $(this).data({ 'name' : 'Cable' });
});
```

I am firing a function base off checkbox selection or label click. This may not be the most efficient way of doing that but it works (not the data part but the function firing)

```
$(this).find('li input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
     $.data($(this).parent().get('name'));
 });

$(this).find('li lable').click(function () {
     $.data($(this).parent().get('name'));
});
```

There is more going on with the jquery in the page then this code, but this should be all that's necessary to see what is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` is a jQuery AJAX method. You should replace `get` by [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$(this).find('li input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
     $.data($(this).parent().data('name'));
 });

$(this).find('li lable').click(function () {
     $.data($(this).parent().data('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the data item `name` from an element, use the `data()` method in your last code snippet like this:

```
var name = $(this).parent().data('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

to get data:

```
var oData = $.data($("body"), "data");
```

so in your case:

```
$(this).find('li input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
     var oData = $.data($(this).parent(), 'name');
 });

$(this).find('li lable').click(function () {
     var oData = $.data($(this).parent(), 'name');
});
```

like @Rob W said `get` is used for ajax call

Reference to JQuery.data: [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your "getter" for the data are wrong. You need to access the selector with `.data('name')`. Try this:

```
$(this).find('li input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
  var data = $(this).parent().data('name');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go with that to store the text of each `<li>`:

```
$(this.BaseElement).find("li").each(function(){
    $(this).data("name", $(this).text());
});
```

But i'm not sure what you're trying to do with the last snippet of code. Updating the data stored when a checkbox is (un)checked?